# How to manage Azure based SQL Server from VS12?

Tags: sql-server, azure, configuration

*I'm not sure if I'm asking the question in the correct way so please be patient. Trying to do my best.   :)*

I have a database in the cloud and installed the required software on my computer (as described in the guidelines on Azure.com). Then , I created a new project in my solution (SQL Server Database) and then I get stuck.

I tried to publish and got a bunch of settings to fill in. Amongs them, I saw a button for *Load Profile* and I wonder if it's so nice that I can obtain a profile from my Azure account for that. And if so, where to get it - I haven't found that anywhere despite a few hours of searching.

Am I totally off on this one? Creating the site was extremely straight-forward so I got my hopes high on the DB part too.

Comment: Well, [This Tutorial](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/multi-tier-web-site/1-overview/) basically has anything you need in order to get your application up and running, and that includes the publishing part...

Comment: @Liel I just read through the whole thing and I got no clarity on my issue (please keep in mind that I'm not sure that I asked my question the right way). I need to know if it's possible to obtain (and if so, where to obtain) a file with configurations so I can use the SQL project in VS12 for building up the structure of my DB in the cloud. Is that doable?

Comment: There are three types of DB building - Code First, Model First, and Database first. Read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907.aspx) for more details. It sounds like you are taking the Model First approach, each should be OK. However, Azure works smoothly and instantly using Code-First approach. Since you are building a new DB from scratch, maybe you would like to consider switching...

Comment: Oh, code first is great. Thanks. But I have two questions about it. First of all, how do I lift the (local) DB to the cloud. Secondly, what if I change the schema of my DB - will I loose the data stored there already?

Comment: You don't "lift" the DB to the cloud. It should be created the same way it is created locally, through the application. And about the DB Changes, what performs the changes are "Migrations". Basically, those are automatically created C# classes, that perform the change on application runtime. You can learn about migrations [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx)

Comment: Cool. Thanks! I feel like a dinosaur. Have been coding for years but this is news to me. Borderline embarrassing, haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Link, you can download your puplish profile if logged in: https://windows.azure.com/download/publishprofile.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0